# How to show a running progress bar while page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I want to show a running progress bar while my page is loading [like here](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/791/Very-Beautiful-CSS3-And-JQuery-progress-bar), in my page. 
I used a simple loading image in my example, but I want to convert it in a running progress bar. Here is my code:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    alert("hi");
    $('#loading').hide();
});
```

```css
#loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 240px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading">
    <img id="loading-image" src="http://cdn.nirmaltv.com/images/generatorphp-thumb.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
<div id="txt">
    <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
</div>
<button>Change Content</button>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xM6v9/645/)

Comment: What makes your site being e.g 50% loaded?

Comment: this is just an example , i want to show a progress bar starting from 1% as page start loading and went up to 100% when loading is done .

Comment: Check out [pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)

Comment: Agree with @Mottie - I use http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/ for my projects too. It's a really nice plugin and it's automatic too, which means all you have to do is include the script.

Answer (score 15):

I have copied the relevant code below from [This page](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/). Hope this might help you.

```
$.ajax({
  xhr: function() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with upload progress
        console.log(percentComplete);
      }
    }, false);
    //Download progress
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with download progress
        console.log(percentComplete);
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/",
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
    //Do something success-ish
  }
});
```

Comment: The OP asked for a page loading progress bar.  You provided an a way to determine upload progress.

Comment: +1 You answered the hardest part of this question--determining a percent of progress.  The "easy" part (the actual progress bar) could be answered many ways, including a jQueryUI progress bar:  http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way.  The OP is looking for a progress bar that display the page load progress.  This answer deals with upload progress.  Upload != download.

Comment: Can't you guys read? It has progress updating for BOTH upload AND download.

Answer (score 11):

It’s a chicken-and-egg problem. You won’t be able to do it because you need to load the assets to display the progress bar widget, by which time your page will be either fully or partially downloaded. Also, you need to know the total size of the page prior to the user requesting in order to calculate a percentage.

It’s more hassle than it’s worth.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but look at my scenario; `index.html` is first sent to client with jQuery already in it, inline - on document ready `$(function() { /* here */ })` I want to grab a huge `.js` file which is around 1MB, thus making sense showing the user a progress bar!

Comment: Loading an asset on demand is not the same as loading a web page, comprising of multiple sources (images, style sheets, JavaScript files etc). You could implement a progress bar for loading a single file on demand, but not for a basic HTTP request for a web page.

Comment: While it may be more hassle than it's worth, I wouldn't say it can't be done, since it obviously HAS been done (eg youtube and more and more others).

Comment: @UяošKoт It can be emulated, yes. But you can’t tell how big a page is until you’ve _actually_ downloaded that page!

Comment: This is the answer that you rarely see around the web, there is not much you can do to measure the webpage overall size over http, and trying to make it real is just inefficient, most developers just create the illusion of loading (by measuring how on average their pages take to load, and make the bar stop short of 100% until it fully loads). This needs to be discussed more openly on the web.

Comment: 1 MB is nothing unless you live in .. well u know what I mean

Comment: @MartinBean: It's been six years since your answer. Do you have a different answer now? I'm asking because I've always wondered how developer calculate loading progress because like you said, you can't tell how big a page is until it has been downloaded.

Comment: @bytrangle It’ll still be difficult to do accurately. Calculating progress is one of those things that’s more difficult than it looks. A response can indicate how many bytes a HTML response is going to be, but that number won’t include the size of any included assets on that page such as images, style sheets, JavaScript files, etc which will be separate HTTP requests.

Answer (score 9):

Simple Steps, follow them and  i guess it will solve your problem

Include these Css in your page,

```
.progress {
      position: relative;
      height: 2px;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      /*margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;*/
      overflow: hidden;

    }
    .progress .indeterminate {
background-color:black; }
    .progress .indeterminate:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #2C67B1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      will-change: left, right;
      -webkit-animation: indeterminate 2.1s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.815, 0.735, 0.395) infinite;
              animation: indeterminate 2.1s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.815, 0.735, 0.395) infinite; }
    .progress .indeterminate:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #2C67B1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      will-change: left, right;
      -webkit-animation: indeterminate-short 2.1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) infinite;
              animation: indeterminate-short 2.1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) infinite;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1.15s;
              animation-delay: 1.15s; }

    @-webkit-keyframes indeterminate {
      0% {
        left: -35%;
        right: 100%; }
      60% {
        left: 100%;
        right: -90%; }
      100% {
        left: 100%;
        right: -90%; } }
    @keyframes indeterminate {
      0% {
        left: -35%;
        right: 100%; }
      60% {
        left: 100%;
        right: -90%; }
      100% {
        left: 100%;
        right: -90%; } }
    @-webkit-keyframes indeterminate-short {
      0% {
        left: -200%;
        right: 100%; }
      60% {
        left: 107%;
        right: -8%; }
      100% {
        left: 107%;
        right: -8%; } }
    @keyframes indeterminate-short {
      0% {
        left: -200%;
        right: 100%; }
      60% {
        left: 107%;
        right: -8%; }
      100% {
        left: 107%;
        right: -8%; } }
```

Then include the progress bar your body tag,

```
<div class="progress" id="PreLoaderBar">
        <div class="indeterminate"></div>
    </div>
```

then it will start as your page loads, and now what you have to do is just hide this when the page loads,or set the visibility to none, or hidden, using javascript,

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                console.log(document.readyState);
                document.getElementById("PreLoaderBar").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

Let me Know if you face any problems and also, you can add any type of progress bar you can easily find them, for this example i have used a indeterminate progress bar.

Comment: awesome answer!

Comment: If anyone will be using this, just a note, style display none wasn't working for me to remove it, so i changed it into $(".PreLoaderBar").css("display", "none"); and used class on it.

Comment: @ikiK I use pure JS and `style.display='none'` is the correct way.

Answer (score 4):

In this sample, I created a JavaScript progress bar (with percentage display), you can control it and hide it with JavaScript.

In this sample, the progress bar advances every 100ms. You can see it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xM6v9/713/)

```
var elapsedTime = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  timer()
}, 100);

function progressbar(percent) {
  document.getElementById("prgsbarcolor").style.width = percent + '%';
  document.getElementById("prgsbartext").innerHTML = percent + '%';
}

function timer() {
  if (elapsedTime > 100) {
    document.getElementById("prgsbartext").style.color = "#FFF";
    document.getElementById("prgsbartext").innerHTML = "Completed.";
    if (elapsedTime >= 107) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      history.go(-1);
    }
  } else {
    progressbar(elapsedTime);
  }
  elapsedTime++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here.

It definitely solves your problem for complete tutorial here is the [link](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/display-progress-bar-while-page-loads-using-jquery.php)

### DEMO

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
      set_ele(all[i]);
    }
  }
}

function check_element(ele) {
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  var totalele = all.length;
  var per_inc = 100 / all.length;

  if ($(ele).on()) {
    var prog_width = per_inc + Number(document.getElementById("progress_width").value);
    document.getElementById("progress_width").value = prog_width;
    $("#bar1").animate({
      width: prog_width + "%"
    }, 10, function() {
      if (document.getElementById("bar1").style.width == "100%") {
        $(".progress").fadeOut("slow");
      }
    });
  } else {
    set_ele(ele);
  }
}

function set_ele(set_element) {
  check_element(set_element);
}
```

```css
body
{
  margin:0px; auto;
  padding:0px;
  font-family:helvetica;
}
.progress 
{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.bar 
{ 
  background-color: #819FF7; 
  width:0%; 
  height:5px; 
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.percent 
{ 
  position:absolute; 
  display:inline-block; 
  top:3px; 
  left:48%; 
}
#wrapper
{
  width:995px;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px auto;
  font-family:helvetica;
  text-align:center;
}
h1
{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-top:60px;
  color:#A9BCF5;
}
h1 p
{
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px;
  font-size:18px;
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='progress' id="progress_div">
   <div class='bar' id='bar1'></div>
   <div class='percent' id='percent1'></div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="content">
     <h1>Display Progress Bar While Page Loads Using jQuery<p>TalkersCode.com</p></h1>
   </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="progress_width" value="0">
```