# Is it possible to check how much bytes get loaded in HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to check how many bytes got loaded in `HTML Page`? If not, then can anyone explain how these `percentage preloader`s work in html pages or tell if they are just an illusion for users?

I want to create a `pre-loader` for my website having functionality similar to `flash pre-loaders`. But can't understand how to check whether each element of website gets loaded or still loading.

Comment: all the info you need is in the "network" tab in Developer Tool like FireBug or Inspector

Comment: This has been discussed here : http://superuser.com/a/333796/154624

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981909/how-to-show-a-running-progress-bar-while-page-is-loading

Comment: Not to demotivate, but till my last project where I just barely managed to get it done was by giving user an illusion. Sad part is its more of an hassle and it worth nothing... Sometime, my progress-bar went directly to 100% from 60% :( . Will definitely bookmark your question , so that I can see a better solution and improve my code.

Comment: @Konvivial, is it worked on not?

Comment: No....For now I just used the delay and get the stuff done without percentage.

Answer (score 3):

It returns the size of the html page in bytes Or you can get the content-length header

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', document.location, false);
request.send();
var size = request.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase().match(/content-length: \d+/);
document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = size + " bytes";
```

Comment: This is a great start.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to get loading progress for the current page.

However, if you are loading anything through AJAX, it's actually quite simple.

The server will (or at least, should) include a `Content-Length` header in the response, which you can read (`xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")`) and you can also read the amount downloaded so far (`xhr.responseText.length`) and work out a percentage.

However, the above won't work in some older browsers - they don't like you accessing `xhr.responseText` before it's fully downloaded.

In more recent browsers, namely those that support "XMLHttpRequest2", you can use the `progress` event and relevant properties to get the progress. [More details on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress), but the general idea is to use `evt.loaded / evt.total` to get the fraction loaded.