# Dropzone.js upload progressbar doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

When I try to upload a big file, the progress bar becomes 100% instantly while in fact the file still in progress, and the progress bar waits as full until it finishes the upload progress. How could I make it as full when the upload progress finished.

[image]

It is waiting like this until it finishes the upload progress.

[image]

And this is when it finished

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866817/is-it-possible-to-check-how-much-bytes-get-loaded-in-html-page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708493/bytes-recieved-and-bytes-total-of-images-via-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Drop zone does not do the uploading progress calculation, you should do it yourself and provide the percentage to the drop zone component.

When you send an upload request trough http request, you can check file size to have the total size for uploading. Then on each response from your server (onData) check how much on the whole file size has been uploaded. Having total size and uploaded size you can set the uploaded percentage for Drop zone.

Also, there is a complete event which fires when the upload is successful or canceled due to an error.