# Calculate and Display Page Weight using Javascript

Tags: javascript

There are js functions to get browser size, window width and scroll position. Is there anything that quickly allows you to interrogate the **total page size or weight**?

Having a google - I can't see anything obvious. Clearly, you can view this using dev tools see below - but my end application requires that I display this within the page after load.

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890221/how-to-get-current-page-size-in-kb-using-just-javascript

Comment: Potentially useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390632/how-to-get-file-size-of-scripts-and-stylesheets-with-javascript (check the request headers using JS)

Comment: You could maybe use a ServiceWorker, this allows you to intercept all HTTP traffic, including fetch requests etc, you could then sum up the bytes downloaded.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: The above 2 links are from 2012 & 2015, things have moved on somewhat, the support table for ServiceWorkers   -> https://caniuse.com/serviceworkers

Comment: Thanks @Keith - your suggestion seems to be a good idea. If you point me to some tutorials on getting started in the answer below I will accept the answer.

Comment: What do you expect from this number? You disabled the cache for the measurement, but actual users in everyday browsing will have it enabled for example.

Answer (score 1):

Get raw page size

```
document.body.innerHTML.length // 100 chars // 100/1024 kilobytes
```

To get total page size

```
document.body.innerHTML.length
+
All css file contents fetch('styles.css').then(v => v.text().length)
+
All js file contents fetch('script.js').then(v => v.text().length)
```