# Fill in transparent logo with percentage of page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to fill in a logo with the percentage of page load.

I'm thinking either with a gif (but can you even sync a gif with % of page load?) or by having, say, 100 images change out based on where the page load percentage is at. ex. `logo_60.png` displays when the page is 60% loaded, etc.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Would loading the image affect page load time?

Comment: Do you already have a means of calculating the percentage of the page that has loaded?

Comment: @robM no I don't yet but I figured I'd find out if it's possible to even control a gif's position in the first place but I did find this- http://stackoverflow.com/a/16572160/6817866

Comment: It is most definitely possible, that's the easy part - determining how much of the page has loaded will be the harder part

Answer (score 0):

It is rather complicated to build somthing that shows loading prgress of the site.
Using a gif is in fact not the way to go since (as you feared) it can't be synced with the progress hence it's not accurate.

I recommend using a ready to use plugin.
See this post:

[How to show a running progress bar while page is loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981909/how-to-show-a-running-progress-bar-while-page-is-loading)