# Where should I put JavaScript's loading screen script on HTML Document?

Tags: javascript

I just made loading screen with Javascript and am wondering which part of HTML Document it must be placed.
I mean on inside of  or before closing  tag???
Some documents say it must be placed on  because it has to be loaded before any contents, but it seems to work well even though I put it before .

Could you tell me which part of HTML Document I "must" or "had better" put the scripts?
Is there difference in case with "defer" or "no defer"??

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.querySelector('#js-loading').classList.add('hide');
});
```

```css
.loading {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-property: visibility, opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.2s; 
}
.loading.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/script.js"></script> //Position A ???
        <script src="js/script.js" defer></script> //Position A with defer???
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loading" id="js-loading">
            <div class="loading-img"><img src="images/loading.svg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div>content</div>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script> //Position B ???
        <script src="js/script.js" defer></script> //Position B with defer???
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) are saying about the `defer` attribute:

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script
>   is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before
>   firing DOMContentLoaded.
>
> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded
>   event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.

Without the `defer` attribute, the scripts would be loaded immediately.

**But in any case and independent of the script tag placement, the scripts will be executed before the `load` event is fired, so every placement is fine for a script, which adds an event listener to the `load` event.**

Gusto-wise, I would place them in the head part, since that is much more clean, especially if you have much content in the body part.

Comment: OK, so every placement is fine.
Also your last comment was useful for me.
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) API to know when the document is completely loaded.

You can refer this answer for more insight.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44715040/7181668

Comment: I didn' t know this way to check. So interesting! I really appreciate you.