# Is it possible to get web-page loading elements progress in percentage?

Tags: javascript, dom

When a web page starts loading for the first time browser download images, javascript, CSS and other assets. I want to measure this loading progress by (%) notations.

To do this script I have explored JavaScript's `window.onload` but I didn't get any properties & methods as required.

```
function load() {
    var preload = document.querySelector('#magic-box');
    preload.style.display="none";
}

window.onload = load;
```

**window.onload** pretty enough for creating a simple preloader for the webpage. In the GitHub & Codepen there are a lot of percentage preloaders. But they are not calculating the absolute percent, They are modified & static. If we can measure webpages elements loading progress we can make an awsome & cool preloader

Comment: As far as I know this can't be done, since the browser does not know how big a ressource is when it starts downloading it. You could precalculate the size of the ressources and then hard code them. Otherwise you can only calculate an estimate. Maybe the [performance api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) can help you. If you preload the new page with an xhr request or using fetch() then it is completely possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show a running progress bar while page is loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981909/how-to-show-a-running-progress-bar-while-page-is-loading)

Answer (score 1):

Check your average latency then use that time for loading percentage.  After that time set your state to loaded

Answer (score 1):

Tracking progress of entire page can be problematic, but tracking a specific resource can be tracked. An xhr request have [`onprogress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent) event. In which you can get total length of the response and currently loaded content.

As an example from [this](https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest) site

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// 2. Configure it: GET-request for the URL /article/.../load
xhr.open('GET', '/article/xmlhttprequest/example/load');

// 3. Send the request over the network
xhr.send();

// 4. This will be called after the response is received
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status != 200) { // analyze HTTP status of the response
    alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found
  } else { // show the result
    alert(`Done, got ${xhr.response.length} bytes`); // responseText is the server
  }
};

xhr.onprogress = function(event) {
  if (event.lengthComputable) {
    console.log(`Received ${event.loaded} of ${event.total} bytes progress -> ${(event.loaded/event.total * 100)}%`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Received ${event.loaded} bytes`); // no Content-Length
  }

};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert("Request failed");
};
```

`xhr.onprogress` is the part where progress can be tracked.